# Clonar elementos com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, formulário, clone

estou enfrentando problemas para clonar elementos com javascript.

O problema:

Conforme imagem abaixo, o formulário contém um **checkbox** que ao clicar executa um função que muda o valor do input **qtd Min**.

Ao clicar no texto **Adicionar Categoria**, cria um clone do formulário completo;

Ao clicar no texto **Adicionar subcategoria**, cria um clone dos inputs **nome, descrição e preço**. Ou seja, é um clone dentro de outro clone. Porém ao clonar esse **formulário** a função do **checkbox** e **subclone** dos inputs não funcionam;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma prática de fazer isso? Preciso criar várias categorias e dentro de cada categoria criar várias subcategorias.

Abaixo o código javascript que estou usando no momento:

```js
//clone categoria /////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#but_addcategoria').click(function(){
   var newel = $('.categoria:last')
   .clone(true)
   .find("input").val("").end()
   $(newel).insertAfter(".categoria:last");
  });
});

//clone subcategoria
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#but_addsubcategoria').click(function(){
   var newel = $('.tb-complementos:last')
   .clone(true)
   .find("input").val("").end();
   $(newel).insertAfter(".tb-complementos:last");
  });
});
```

Fico muito grato se os amigos puderem me ajudar.

Comment: inclua o html em sua pergunta, [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Quando se trabalhe com criação de objetos dinâmicos, costumamos colocar o evento no formulário e posteriormente localizar os objetos descendentes dentro desse formulário.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_do_formulário').on('click', '#but_addcategoria', function(){ //clone categoria
        var newel = $('.categoria:last')
        .clone(true)
        .find("input").val("").end()
        $(newel).insertAfter(".categoria:last");
    }).on('click', '#but_addsubcategoria', function(){ //clone subcategoria
        var newel = $('.tb-complementos:last')
        .clone(true)
        .find("input").val("").end();
        $(newel).insertAfter(".tb-complementos:last");
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não consegui reproduzir o problema, realmente está faltando o seu HTML aqui para facilitar as respostas, mas tente assim pra ver se resolve:

```
const otherClickListeners = () => {
    $('#but_addsubcategoria').click(function(){
      var newel = $('.tb-complementos:last')
        .clone(true)
        .find("input").val("").end();
      $(newel).insertAfter(".tb-complementos:last");
     });
    // Aqui o código para iniciar o click listenner do checkbox, que não estava no seu código
}

//clone categoria /////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#but_addcategoria').click(function(){
      var newel = $('.categoria:last')
        .clone(true)
        .find("input").val("").end()
      $(newel).insertAfter(".categoria:last");
      otherClickListeners();
    });
    otherClickListeners();
});
```

Talvez reiniciar o listenner dos elementos clonados toda vez que eles forem clonados resolva o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Galera, muito obrigado pelas respostas, foram muito úteis.
O seguinte código resolveu o problema...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#but_add').click(function(){ 
   var newel = $('.categoria:last')
   .clone(true)
   .find("input").val("").end()   
   $(newel).insertAfter(".categoria:last");
  });
});
//add subcategoria
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#but_add_c').click(function(){
   var newel = $('.tb-complementos:last')
   .clone(true)
   .find("input").val("").end();
   $(newel).insertBefore(this);
  });
});
```